# Spring boot - Embeded Tomcat HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I'm using Java 7, Spring-Boot 1.1.7 and an ambeded Tomcat 7.

In the past, when I used a stand alone Tomcat, I used to add an http connector, that will redirect the requests to the HTTPS port :

```
<Connector port="8080" enableLookups="false"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

How can I do it when I'm using an embeded Tomcat (and I dont have a server.xml file) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `Connector` or configure the existing one with its Java API (e.g. see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-enable-multiple-connectors-in-tomcat). The `Connector` has a `setRedirectPort()` (it's mapped directly by the XML `<Connector/>` element).

Comment: Adding a connecter and setting the HTTP port was not enough, I had to use @Andy Wilkinson's .answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655875/spring-boot-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: Could you give an example please