# Spring Cloud Gateway+Consul configurations

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

We are using Spring Cloud Gateway before multiple microservices with consul as service discovery. There are several microservices developed in different languages.

Please find ***build.gradle*** for the application

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', 'Greenwich.RELEASE')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-tcnative-boringssl-static', version: '2.0.20.Final'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Below is the example of API gateway configuration 
***application.yaml***

```
server:
  port: 10000
  http:
    port: 9000
  # enable HTTP2
  http2:
    enabled: true
  # enable compression
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: /var/.conf/self-signed.p12
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store-password: "something"
    key-alias: athenasowl
    trust-store: /var/.conf/self-signe.p12
    trust-store-password: "something"
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          predicates:
          - Path="'/api/' + serviceId + '/**'"
          filters:
          - RewritePath="'/api/' + serviceId + '/(?<remaining>.*)'", "serviceId + '/${remaining}'"
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  server:
    port: 10001
    ssl:
      enabled: false
  endpoint:
    gateway:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
    health:
      sensitive: false
logging:
  level:
    root: DEBUG
    org:
      springframework:
        web: INFO
  pattern:
    console: "%-5level %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%F:%L] VTC : %msg%n"
    file: "%-5level %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%F:%L] VTC : %msg%n"
  file: /tmp/log_files/apigateway.log
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

There are a few configuration issues which we are facing, they are listed below:

- ***Rewrite URL prefixed with /api/ to respective serviceId registered on consul***: We tried to configure predicate to get path prefixed with ***api*** to rewrite path and remove ***api***, but still it's not working. So there is another service ***/hello-service/*** registered with consul server, but we want to do API call with ***/api/hello-service/***
- ***Redirect unmatched request to default path***: We want to redirect all unmatched request to UI.
- ***Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS on spring cloud gateway***: We want to force all request coming to spring gateway to be https
- ***Forwarding HTTPS request to HTTP serviceId registered with consul***: Services registered with consul are on HTTP except for the API gateway, we want to be able to send HTTPS request to HTTP backend i.e. terminating HTTPS at API Gateway only.

Any help in solving the above issue would be good

**Edit 1:**
After some help from @spencergibb, we had setup the spring cloud gateway with https. But There are some additional issues which we faced

- If HTTPS is enabled on both API gateway and service both, we received below error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out   at
>   io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source)
>   ~[netty-handler-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.

- If HTTPS is enabled on only API gateway, we received below error

  > There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
  >   org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND
  >   and received

  for path `https://localhost:8443/api/hello-service/hello/message`

  > Unable to Connect

  for path `http://localhost:8080/hello-service/hello/message`

Please find the link for the [sample applications](https://github.com/nitishkumar71/api-gateway-sample)

**Instructions:**

- navigate to consul directory and Start consul server using command `./consul agent -dev`
- run api-gateway spring boot gradle project
- run rest-demo spring boot gradle project

**Edit 2**

Thank You @spencergibb, We were able to successfully apply ssl on gateway and call the registered services on HTTP. Since [Spring Webflux with Netty does not support listening on two ports](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12035), we created an additional tcp server bind to http port based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53000573/1825578).

There is still some issue we are facing with `RewritePath` for `/api/` rule

```
  predicates:
    - name: Path
      args:
        pattern: "'/api/'+serviceId.toLowerCase()+'/**'"
  filters:
    - name: RewritePath
      args:
        regexp: "'/api/' + serviceId.toLowerCase() + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
        replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
```

below is the complete trace for the request

> DEBUG 13-02-2019 03:32:01 [FilteringWebHandler.java:86] VTC : Sorted
>   gatewayFilterFactories:
>   [OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@257505fd},
>   order=-2147482648},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@400caab4},
>   order=-2147473648},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@36e2c50b},
>   order=-1},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@66f0c66d}, order=0},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory$$Lambda$360/1720581802@5821f2e6,
>   order=0},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@27119239},
>   order=10000},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter@568a9d8f},
>   order=10100},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@6ba77da3},
>   order=2147483646},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@73c24516},
>   order=2147483647},
>   OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@461a9938},
>   order=2147483647}] TRACE 13-02-2019 03:32:01
>   [RouteToRequestUrlFilter.java:59] VTC : RouteToRequestUrlFilter start
>   TRACE 13-02-2019 03:32:02 [NettyWriteResponseFilter.java:68] VTC :
>   NettyWriteResponseFilter start TRACE 13-02-2019 03:32:02
>   [GatewayMetricsFilter.java:101] VTC : Stopping timer
>   'gateway.requests' with tags
>   [tag(outcome=CLIENT_ERROR),tag(routeId=rewrite_response_upper),tag(routeUri=http://httpbin.org:80),tag(status=NOT_FOUN

Comment: I can try and help Monday

Comment: Thank you @spencergibb meanwhile, we will also try to solve some of those issues.

Comment: Hi @spencergibb did you get any chance to look into it?

Comment: You need to have a slash before the replacement in `RewritePath` `"/serviceId + '/${remaining}'"`. To match the UI create a route with path `/**` manually. Redirecting http to https, if there's not something in spring security (which there likely is) you'd need to write a filter. For https to http it should work like that automatically, what version are you using?

Comment: All the dependencies are associated with spring boot version `2.1.2•RELEASE`

Comment: Hi @spencergibb, we tried the mentioned approach but it didn't work with http or https. We have also included git repo link above for the demo applications.

Comment: So you can't use the shortcut for configuring the discovery locator
https://gist.github.com/spencergibb/7e49b72e55bc29767dad1faf460cc056

Comment: Removing http2 and httpclient.ssl settings from gateway config let me get all the way thru. Gist above has full settings

Comment: Thank you so much @spencergibb, but `RewritePath` is not working as expected, have included more information about it.

Comment: @spencergibb - can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662179/consul-with-spring-cloud-gateway-inter-service-communication as well?

NitishkumarSingh - sorry for hijacking your thread.

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh I don't understand what isn't working, those logs don't tell me anything. I successfully made requests with your project.

Comment: @Mubin indeed you shouldn't ask about other questions. I monitor the tag.

Comment: @spencergibb: sorry about the confusion, it worked. Thank you so much. Can you please put it as answer, so I can accept the answer.

Comment: will do that right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of things were needed

1. disable http2
2. Disable ssl configuration of httpclient
3. Update `locator` predicates and filters to use verbose configuration.

Here is the resulting portions of application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8443
  http:
    port: 8080
  servlet:
  # enable HTTP2
#  http2:
#    enabled: true
  # enable compression

# ... removed for brevity

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: true
    gateway:
#      httpclient:
#        ssl:
#          handshake-timeout-millis: 10000
#          close-notify-flush-timeout-millis: 3000
#          close-notify-read-timeout-millis: 0
#      routes:
      # - id: ui_path_route
      #   predicates:
      #   - Path="'/**'"
      #   filters:
      #   - RewritePath="'/**'", "/ui"
      discovery:
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
        locator:
          enabled: true
          predicates:
          - name: Path
            args:
              pattern: "'/api/' + serviceId + '/**'"
          filters:
          - name: RewritePath
            args:
              regexp: "'/api/' + serviceId + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
              replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
#... removed for brevity
```