# Spring MVC app redirects to https:// site, need http://

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

So I have a Spring website which is `https://`. At one point I need to redirect a user from a link clicked on my site to an `http://` site. I'm doing this with a click on https://mywebsite.com/redirect/some-key.

In my Java backend, I'm taking the `some-key` and redirecting the browser to an `http://` link with `return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("http://somewhere.com", false, true));` (false referring to relative context, true referring to http10Compatible).

Instead of redirecting to the `http://somewhere.com` site, it redirects to `https://somewhere.com`.

I know there should be a straightforward way to do this, just feel lost currently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655875/spring-boot-redirect-http-to-https)