# Spring Boot Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Same Port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, tomcat, https

I have a Spring Boot 1.5.21 application which runs on HTTPS. I want to redirect HTTP requests into HTTPS for same port. My `application.yaml` is as follows:

```
server:
  port: 8443
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled:  false
  ssl:
    key-store:  classpath:keystore/tomcat.p12
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store-password: password
    key-alias:  tomcat
```

When I enter this into URL bar:

```
http://localhost:8443
```

I see that error as usual:

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

When I refresh the page, doesn't happen. When I click the URL bar and click enter again at Chrome, link is redirected.

My questions:

1. How can I make that URL:

`http://localhost:8443`

automatically redirect to:

`https://localhost:8443`

2. If below is not applicable, how can I remove that message?

There is a similar question here which asks for different ports and answer does not work for my case:
[Spring Boot redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655875/spring-boot-redirect-http-to-https)

Comment: Are you using any web servers like nginx? If so we can make the configurations in the nginx config

Comment: Embedded tomcat which comes with Spring Boot as default.

Comment: How I did it is I had a nginx which proxy passed the http request to 443 which forwarded to application port. In places where did not have nginx we did it using load balancer.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I ran into the same problem.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem? I am also interested into this issue.

Comment: please post a solution, if someone find it !!!