# Enable redirect in Spring boot from http to https using single port

Tags: spring-boot, https

We are trying to enable https for our services but it is currently used by legacy systems that can't be changed.

My idea was to use a single port 8080 so that the user can either use http://my-app:8080 (for existing systems) or https://my-app:8080 (for new systems). It will just redirect from http to https and but still works if https is used.

There is an existing question about this but was not answered: [Spring Boot Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Same Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640108/spring-boot-redirect-http-to-https-on-same-port)

So far all the examples I saw were using different ports for http and https. Is this how it should be? or Is it even possible to use a single port for both? If possible how?

Comment: probably you can have it running behind a reverse proxy

Comment: We end up using two ports, well as long as the legacy systems are unaffected, it's cool.

Comment: How did you use two ports?

Comment: I run it behind proxy server. We're using 8080 for http then 443 for https. We just followed this article https://geocolumbus.github.io/HTTPS-ELB-AWS-Spring-Boot/